# Compilation error when installing Protocol Buffers

Tags: java, installation, protocol-buffers

Have been trying to install Protocol Buffers compiler and java runtime installation, but I'm getting an error when compiling the java classes. I downloaded:

- protoc-3.2.0rc2-linux-x86_64.zip (although it says the version is 2.6.1)
- protobuf-java-3.2.0rc2.zip

The file structure looks like this:

- project/

  - protobuf_dir/

    - the protobuf files/directories including src/ and java/
    - src/

      - protoc (binary)
      - protoc_dir/ (the other bits and bobs from protoc zip file)
    - java/

      - core/
      - lite/
      - ...

So assuming that's all fine, I typed in:

```
protoc --java_out=src/main/java -I../src \../src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto
```

So protoc seems to be working fine. But then I kept getting errors like these until I commented them out (not sure if that is a problem?):

```
google/protobuf/descriptor.proto:443:3: Expected "required", "optional", or "repeated".
google/protobuf/descriptor.proto:443:12: Expected field name.
google/protobuf/descriptor.proto:541:3: Expected "required", "optional", or "repeated".
google/protobuf/descriptor.proto:541:12: Expected field name.
```

But when I try compiling all the java classes, I just keep getting an error saying:

```
Descriptors.java:1175: error: cannot find symbol
    return FieldDescriptorProto.Type.forNumber(ordinal() + 1);
```

Any ideas on how to solve the problem? Can't see why it shouldn't compile. Tried looking on Google's page but nothing comes up on this.

Aware I sound a bit clueless although I've never really used libraries like protobuf from Github before so this is all new to me!

EDIT: Hi all, this issue was resolved with exactly the same file structure. I uninstalled protoc2.6.1, set my $JAVA_HOME and $PATH variables (you should store them too rather than having to export them every time), installed maven (properly).

All is well! Everything compiled without a hitch. Thanks to the responder!

Comment: What does descriptor.proto look like?

Comment: @JoeC not quite sure what you're asking for exactly. The file can be found at this link (https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto) and the syntax field is set to "proto2" if that means anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> protoc-3.2.0rc2-linux-x86_64.zip (although it says the version is 2.6.1)

This is the problem -- you are somehow using protoc 2.6.1 and not 3.2.0. This could be because protoc 2.6.1 was already installed on your system, and somehow it is taking precedence over 3.2.0. If you look at the errors in descriptor.proto, you'll notice they happen on the `reserved` keyword, which is new; 2.6.1 didn't support it.

It's important to use exactly the same version of protoc as the Java runtime library, otherwise the generated code may not compile correctly, or may compile but not run correctly.

Comment: That makes sense! Any idea on how I might remove 2.6.1?

Comment: @DanielSoutar Depends on how you installed it in the first place. :)

Answer (score -1):

tldr `Again, be sure to check that the version number matches (or is newer than) the version number of protoc that you are using.`

link to official github: [github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/main/java#gradle)

Comment: This doesn't add anything to *my* old question with an accepted answer - if you're just doing this to boost your points.

Comment: you are saying that the exact same version is needed. maybe was accurate back then. the docs these days say: `matches (or is newer than)`